# Is a python list a circular data structure?

Tags: python, list, indexing

i am confuse at some point in my python code,  i am trying to build a program which return the cumulative sum,  that is where is the ith element is the sun of first i+1 elements from the origional list. So cunmulative sum of [1,2,3] is [1,3,6],  i tried to build program and its working but for first element its adding last element as previous element,  that made me think that is structure of python list something circle??

```
h=[]
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(a)):
  d=a[i]+(a[i-1]+1)
  h.append(d)

print(h)
```

Result

```
[8, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Comment: you will need to keep a separate variable with the accumulation value. You wont be able to calculate it from the previous element in the input list alone.

Comment: You probably intended to take the current element from  `a` and the previous element from `h`, thus accumulating the sum. However that has a distinct problem of starting the algorithm where `h` is empty. Thus, keeping a separate variable as Paul mentioned is the easiest way to go.

Comment: No, the "structure" isn't circular, but *negative indices index from the back*. I.e. `my_list[len(my_list) - 1] == my_list[-1]`

Comment: Also worth noting you could use `itertools.accumulate` to achieve this, i.e. `list(accumulate(a))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is with `a[i - 1]` in the 0<sup>th</sup> iteration:

```
d = a[i] + (a[i - 1] + 1)
```

What actually happens is that `i - 1` is reduced to `-1`, and in python, `a[-1]` refers to the last element in the list:

```
In [568]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [569]: l[-1]
Out[569]: 4
```

---

The solution here would be to start your loop from 1. Alternatively, you would consider the use of a temp variable, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269917/is-python-list-circle-structure/46269951#comment79502366_46269917):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
h = []
cumsum = 0
for i in a:
    cumsum += i
    h.append(cumsum)

print(h)
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

---

As a side, if you're using `numpy`, this is as simple as a single function call with `np.cumsum`:

```
h = np.cumsum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
print(h)
array([ 1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that you could use `itertools.accumulate` to accumulate the results of a binary operation, in this case, addition. Note, `itertools.accumulate` actually *defaults to addition*:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

But you could pass it a binary operation and do a cumulative product, for example:

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a ,lambda x, y: x*y))
```

Better yet, harness the power of the `operator` module:

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a, operator.add)) #cumulative sum
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a, operator.mul)) #cumulative product
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a, operator.truediv)) #cumulative quotient
[1, 0.5, 0.16666666666666666, 0.041666666666666664, 0.008333333333333333, 0.001388888888888889]
>>> list(itertools.accumulate(a, operator.floordiv)) #cumulative floor div
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is a little like that. In python a[-1] gives you the last element of the list.

If you seed the result with the first item your code and start from 1 rather than 0 can be made to work:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
h=[a[0]]
for i in range(1,len(a)):
  d=a[i]+(h[i-1])
  h.append(d)

print(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lists are not circular, but the can be referenced from either the beginning or the end.  You can use [-1] to reference from the end of the list.

But, if you try to reference the 20th element of a list that only has 10 elements, you will receive an error.  If lists were circular, it would refer to the 10th element, but it does not.

What you want is this, I believe:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
h = []

index = 0
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    first =  a[index]
    second = a[index + 1]
    summation = first + second
    h.append(summation)
    index += 1

print(h)
```